# An efficient algorithm for finding the house number on the opposite side of the street

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

I am trying to write an efficient algorithm in JavaScript to solve this task. Please see below examples of input data, correct results, and my inefficient solution.

**Street example**

```
1|   |6
3|   |4
5|   |2
```

Odd house numbers decrease on the left, even house numbers increase on the right. House numbers start at 1 and increase without gaps.

As input, I have a house number (a) and length of the street (n). I must find the house number on the opposite side of the street.

```
getOppositeHouse(a, n)
getOppositeHouse(1, 3) = 6
getOppositeHouse(3, 3) = 4
getOppositeHouse(2, 3) = 5
getOppositeHouse(3, 5) = 8
```

**My current solution**

```
function getOppositeHouse(a, n) {
  let housesL = [], housesR = [];
  
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2 * n; i += 1)
    if (i % 2) housesL = [...housesL, i];
    else housesR = [i, ...housesR];
  
  if (housesL.includes(a)) return housesR[housesL.indexOf(a)];
  else return housesL[housesR.indexOf(a)];
}
```

Execution time for a = 20 and n = 100000 on my PC is 138.7 seconds. Please help me to create a more efficient solution.

Comment: instead of looping use some math, i.e. if house number given is odd, we knwo which house on the street it is by formula `(a+1)/2)`, then considering houses are in reverse on other side we need `n - (a+1)/2 + 1`th house on even side which gives us formula `(n - (a+1)/2 + 1)*2`, we can use similar reasoning for even house number case

Comment: In my country, house numbers on both sides of the street increase in the same direction?

Comment: @Bergi in logical countries. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the opposite house numbers is constant and is equal to `2n + 1`.

```
1 + 6
3 + 4
5 + 2
```

So, you just need to subtract `a` from it get the opposite house number:

```js
function getOppositeHouse(a, n) {
  console.log(2 * n + 1 - a)
}

getOppositeHouse(1, 3) // 6
getOppositeHouse(3, 3) // 4
getOppositeHouse(2, 3) // 5
getOppositeHouse(3, 5) // 8
```